# MySQL Count Distinct - Very Slow

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I have a very big MySQL InnoDB table with following structure:

```
TABLE `whois_records` (
  `record_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `domain_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tld_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiry_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `query_time` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

PRIMARY KEY (`record_id`)
UNIQUE KEY `domain_time` (`domain_name`,`query_time`)
INDEX `tld_id` (`tld_id`)
```

This table currently has 10 Million rows.
It stores frequently updated details of domain names.
So there can be multiple records for same domain name in the table.

TLD ID is the numeric value of the type of domain extension.

Problem is when I'm trying to count the total number of domain names of a particular TLD.

I have tried the following 3 SQL queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(domain_name)) FROM `whois_records` WHERE tld_id=159
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `whois_records` WHERE tld_id=159 GROUP BY domain_name
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT 1 FROM `whois_records` WHERE tld_id=159 GROUP BY domain_name) q
```

All the 3 are very slow, taking between 5 to 10 minutes. It is also using up a lot of CPU to complete. There is INDEX defined on the TLD ID column, so these queries might be doing a FULL INDEX SCAN. It is still very slow. TLD ID of 159 is for ".com", which are the most in number. So when doing a search for 159, it is slowest. For non-popular TLD, with less than 100 domains, the same query takes around 0.10 seconds. TLD ID 159 has around 6 Million records, which is 60% of the entire table consisting of 10 Million rows.

Is there any way to optimize the calculation?

As table grows, the current queries will take longer. So please can anyone help me with a future proof solution to this problem. Is any alteration of table required? Plz help, thank you :)

Comment: Share your my.cnf configuration file and server configuration (CPU, memory, drive type, dedicated machine or not). That all is critical to point you in to the right direction.

Comment: Second question: can *tld_id* be null? If not please make a scheme change before anything else. Nullified fields (can be NULL) slow down lookup dramatically.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, tld_id can have NULL, for unrecognized domain extensions. Should I remove NULL, and change all NULL to 0 ?

Comment: yes, if application logic can handle that. But this is only the start. Pleas share server config

Comment: The problem is cardinality, if your condition return a majority of rows from the table, index seeks or loose index scans which are very fast become useless.So the most you can hope for is an index scan and even that might not be an option if the mysql optimizer thinks so.In short there are too many values for indexes to make sense

Comment: Yes, application logic can handle 0 in place of NULL. That's not an issue. I felt using NULL was better and would use less space and queries would be faster.

Comment: Database is on Amazon RDS - db.m3.xlarge (4 CPU, 15 GB RAM).

Comment: Database is not accessible to Public, as of now. So CPU usage always remains around 1-2%. But when I start counting the unique domain names, CPU shoots up to 40-50% and everything gets slow.

Comment: @Anatoly - I'm not convinced that `NULL` matters in this case.  Think of NULL as being a value that precedes all other values in the index.  Then, `WHERE tld_id=159` is still a simple BTree lookup.

Comment: I could not try checking with NULL optimization, as it required table alteration. And MySQL was taking ages for alteration to complete. It was in "copy to tmp table" stage for many hours. So no point waiting, as the addition of domain_name in tld_id index solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend the index to contain `domain_name` as well:

```
INDEX `tld_id` (`tld_id`, `domain_name`)
```

This should make MySQL use only the index and not table data to compute the result. If the combination of both values is unique, instead add a new unique index:

```
UNIQUE INDEX `new_index` (`tld_id`, `domain_name`)
```

I doubt you can push it a lot further than that. If it is still not fast enough, think about caching the counters.

Comment: Combination of tld_id and domain_name is not unqiue, for a domain like "example.com", there would be multiple rows with value: example.com,159

Comment: Thanks, your method worked. Included the 'domain_name' in the 'tld_id' index, and the total query time and cpu usage came down by 75%. Plus the MySQL Explain is now showing "Using index" in last column. Earlier it was showing "NULL". But one thing, the table size increased by 5%. This must be for the new INDEX. Thanks a lot for the solution :)

Comment: @SadasivaUlaka composite index helped, that's great! How much time reduced down? Is that acceptable or you are looking for additional optimisation techniques?

Comment: Hi Anatoly, there are total 1000 TLD which gets processed every day. So every day, a PHP script runs and executes this SQL 1000 times. Previously the script would take around 20 mins to complete. Now it's just taking 90 seconds. Plus the RDS CloudWatch Monitoring system is not showing anymore CPU spikes, and CPU is always below 5% when this script runs. This is acceptable for us. Btw, removing NULL and changing NULL values to 0 was done. But altering the column from NULL to NOT NULL was taking hours and hours, so we could not complete that change. Right now the columns are using NULL as before

Comment: `Using index` is good -- it indicates that the query is being done entirely in the BTree for that index.  Table size increaded 5% -- does that include the indexes?  How many rows for 159?  The query time should now be roughly proportional to that count.

Comment: 5% size increase includes the index. For "tld_id=159" total rows = 7,505,822 as of now. Query time is very good, plus CPU is much more relaxed now.

Comment: @SadasivaUlaka I totally agree with you, if *the execution time fits well in requirements* now there is no point to over-optimise it. Alter table is the combination of creating new table, modifying its scheme, copying all data, drop old table, so this is not surprisingly to see it takes hours.

Comment: @Anatoly - Yes, that's true. ALTER TABLE in MySQL is not that useful for huge tables, as of now. Waiting for hours and days seems total waste of time. I had upgraded the RDS instance to (8 CPU / 30 GB RAM) before issuing the ALTER TABLE statement. Still it was on "copy to tmp table" stage  for nearly 4 hours. So cancelled the process, as it could have taken many more hours or days, who knows?

Comment: @SadasivaUlaka maybe it can be an option to drop indexes first, alter, than add index again, like Percona recommends [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/12/09/thinking-about-running-optimize-on-your-innodb-table-stop/). Recommended to try on slave first, not production. Sorry, If I confuse you, I don't recommend to spend extra time if request time met requirements. What would I do is to make sure I followed common DBA recommendation, then start thinking about application logic change + different strategy to store/split tables and other techniques. It makes sense if data grows quickly.

Comment: Before anything comes integrity. `NULL` is needed here to denote the non-existence of a corresponding TLD entry in the other table and in this case `NULL` is not equal to `0`.